# mongoose query pending after a reconnection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a nodejs api with koajs(v1.2.0), a mongodb database and use mongoose(v4.7.3) to access my datas.
My db is a replica set located on the cloud and the code for the connection looks like this:

```
const options = {
  socketOptions: {
    socketTimeoutMS: 0,
    keepAlive: true
  },
  auto_reconnect: true,
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE
}
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL, {
  server: options,
  replset: options
});
```

Everything works but when i tried to turn off my wifi and then turn on again, I can see

```
mongoose.connection.readyState
```

going from 1(connected) to 0(disconnected) and then 1(connected) again which is correct.
But when i tried to call an api endpoint that query the db:

```
function *example() {
  let data
  try {
    data = yield model.findOne({});
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('e', err);
  }
  this.body = data;
}
```

The query is suspended and after a while it will return without getting the data from mongo.
In chrome debugging console the status of the request is (failed) net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Edit: To reproduce the error : https://github.com/superphung/mongoose-query-pending (follow instruction in the readme).
I notice that the behaviour is different if I use a replica set or a standalone mongodb. With a replica set, the nodejs does not crash if I remove wifi but the query is pending after a reconnection. With a standalone mongo, the app crashed if I disable the wifi connection.

Comment: Can you show a more "complete" and "minimal" example that everyone can just execute to reproduce the same result please. The replica set should not have anything to do with this as this simply should be about the "retry" when a connection is unreachable. This should ( as does with others code ) work and even "queue" any operations attempted when the connection was not present. You're doing something different from what "should" be happening, so a "complete" example will make it clear exactly what that is.

Comment: I just updated my post. I have an exemple to reproduce the bug at this address https://github.com/superphung/mongoose-query-pending. The result is different whether is a standalone or replica set.

Comment: but what I want to understand is the case with the replica set when the query is pending